# Three.js : How to add a 3D JSON model to one face of the cube's mesh

Tags: three.js, model, 3d, load, cube

I am working on a small prototype in Three.js. I need to add a 3D JSON model to one of the faces of the cuboid. I can load the 3D model into the scene, but I couldn't able to add that model to the specific face of the cube.

Three.js script

```
 boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(25, 25, 90, 7, 7, 7);
    var material = [
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#000000", wireframe:true}),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#000000", wireframe:true}),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#000000", wireframe:true}),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#666699", wireframe:false}),
      // load 3D truck model to the mesh here, instead of the image
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SatheeshKS10/MockRest/master/truck-front.png'), wireframe:false } ),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#000000", wireframe:true})
  ];
```

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/SatheeshKS10/ThreeJs)

Comment: You're trying to load a 3D model into a material? What do you mean "add that model to the face"? Why don't you just change the position of the model so it sits on top of the face you want? You could then use a [`THREE.Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Group) to group the cube and the truck together.

Comment: yeah, I tried changing the position of the x, y, z axis of the model. But I am unable to rotate the object in a proper way to align it to the cuboid, resulting in both the model and cuboid where in different position. Can you tell me how to align them together ? I will try with the Three.Group functionality.

Comment: Actually "add that model to the face" means, currently I have a image loaded on to the face of the cuboid. Which I want to replace it with the 3D model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps some one !!

As @Marquizzo mentioned we need to position / rotate the 3D object as required to place them on the exact position in the scene. Three.js offers many methods to parse different formats of 3D objects like - [OBJLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader), [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader), etc.

Below is a simple example using OBJ loader.

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setTexturePath('/resources/');
mtlLoader.setPath('/resources/');
mtlLoader.load('3DModel.mtl', function(materials) { // this is optional to load material files !!
                                                    //  we can skip this if we have only obj files for our 3D model
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath('/resources/');
        objLoader.load('3DModel.obj', function(object3) {
            object3.rotation.set(3.15, 1.55, 0);
            object3.position.y = -25;
            object3.position.z = 10; 
            object3.position.x = 0; 
            scene.add(object3);     // Object is added to the scene.
        });

    });
```

In the above code snippet, first we will load the MTL file 
and then we will load the 3D model's OBJ file.

Next we will rotate & position the object to set it to the corresponding position.